# lxml - how to get minimal xpath of element?

Tags: python, xpath, xml-parsing, html-parsing, lxml

`tree.xpath("/exact/path/to/element")` yields `[<Element I want>]`.

`exact/path/to/element` is procured by a call to `tree.getroottree().getpath(element)`.

If I find the minimal xpath to the element with e.g. Firebug, `tree.xpath("//@minimal-descriptor")` yields `[<Element I want>]`.

**Question**

How do I get the *minimal* xpath from `element` using lxml, or other Python library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not possible** to make lxml generate any xpath expression except [the "absolute" one](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#generating-xpath-expressions) most importantly because there could be enormous amount of xpath expressions pointing to an element.

There are also several important points raised here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171759/xpath-generator

---

As far as I understand from the [`firebug` documentation](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Context_Menu) and the relevant ["Split current option "Copy XPath" into two options for copying the absolute and relative XPath" issue](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7120), the "Copy Minimal XPath" functionality works only on the elements with `id` attribute set:

> Copy Minimal XPath - Node with ID - Copies the minimal version of an
>   XPath to the current node to the clipboard

Comment: How's firebug doing it then?

Comment: @WalrustheCat First of all, we are still talking specifically about `lxml`, right? :) I've updated the answer adding some notes about the `firebug`. Thanks.

Comment: thank *you*.  we are still talking about lxml, and i'm not above modding it.  i thought you were saying the task wasn't possible at all.  if there are other other python APIs that can do this, I'd be open to hearing about it. i'll update my question to reflect this.